# How to resolve no module found error while connecting mysqldb in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import movies
  File "/home/xyz/topmovies/sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    import config
  File "/home/xyz/topmovies/config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I successfully install mysqldb module by using different commands like pip, easy etc, I tried all these commands,

```
sudo pip install MYSQL-python
sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
pip3 install http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip.
```

But i'm getting this error again and again. please help me.

Comment: Afaik `mysql-python` does not support python3, are you sure it was installed properly?

Comment: Yeah the above mentioned commands executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
python3 -m pip install mysql-python
*OR*
python3 -m pip install mysqlclient

Comment: First command return this error: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mn7brn38/mysql-python/
"

Comment: second command executes successfully("Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/xyz/.cache/pip/wheels/df/bb/60/bf7c315cbe163515db1c846e4ffa5557dd785c82e82f3492e8
Successfully built mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.12
") but still i get same no mysqldb module error.

Comment: Try python3 -m pip install mysqlclient. It should definitely work.

Comment: I'm getting this error while executing this command "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r5q_03e3/mysql-python/
"